# Iterating through multiple files in a folder (cypress)

Tags: node.js, testing, cypress, fixtures

I've got multiple json files in a folder which i need to read one by one for testing API. How can i read each file and use it in a different test.
Currently I'm reading files using `cy.task()`, but `cy.task()` is not available outside `it()`

```
describe("Test JSON", () => {
  it(`get file located on test folder`, () => {
    cy.task("getFiles", "cypress/fixtures/jsons/").then((files) => {
      files.forEach((file) => {
      cy.fixture(`jsons/${file}`).then((testJson) => {
            cy.request({
              method: "POST",
              url: Cypress.config().baseUrl,
              body: testJson,
            }).then((response) => {
              expect(response.status).equal(200);
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
});
```

(getFiles is a plugin to read filenames in a directory using fs)

How can i run different tests for different files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `cypress.config.js` with task definition looks like this

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const fs = require('fs')

const getFiles = (path) => {
  return fs.readdirSync(`${__dirname}/${path}`)
}

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        getFiles(path) {
          return getFiles(path)
        }
      })
    },
  },
});
```

invoke `getFiles()` inside `setupNodeEvents` and add the list of files to `config.env`

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const fs = require('fs')

const getFiles = (path) => {
  return fs.readdirSync(`${__dirname}/${path}`)
}

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      config.env.jsonFiles = getFiles('cypress/fixtures/jsons/')
      return config
    },
  },
});
```

In the test, read the files from `Cypress.env()`

```js
const files = Cypress.env('jsonFiles')

files.forEach((file) => {

  it(`tests "${file}"`, () => {
    cy.fixture(`jsons/${file}`).then((testJson) => {
      ...
    })
  })
})
```

---

If you want a different set per spec, add multiple locations to `Cypress.env()`

```js
config.env.jsonFiles1 = getFiles('cypress/fixtures/jsons1/')
config.env.jsonFiles2 = getFiles('cypress/fixtures/jsons2/')
```

Or you can experiment with [fs-readdir-recursive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-readdir-recursive) and read everything in `/fixtures` and folders below.